# jquery append json url into href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a json file and I can add a link as plain text to the body of articles, but I want to add the link to the href and add hand written content in the a tag:

```
$('div#similarArticles').html(treeObj.root[clickedID - 1].Link);
```

.. how can I go about this?

```
    <div id="articles">
    <div id="similarArticles">
        <a href="#"></a>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: what about $('div#similarArticles').find('a').attr('href',treeObj.root[clickedID - 1].Link);

Comment: hmm doesn't show anything

Comment: Doesn't show because you need to inspect element the a tag to see the dom attribute.

Comment: are you trying to insert content into the anchor tag as well as set the value of the href?

Comment: yes I am, forgot @NorlihazmeyGhazali method would be blank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify the `<a>`, not the `<div>`:

```
var link = treeObj.root[clickedID - 1].Link;
$("#similarArticles a").attr('href', link).text(handWrittenContent);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this

```
var link = treeObj.root[clickedID - 1].Link;
$("#similarArticles").find('a').attr('href', link).text('thelinktext');
```

With jQuery 1.6 and above you can use:

```
 $("#similarArticles").find('a').prop('href', link).text('thelinktext');
```